# Tinymce Advanced is not showing table button in pages.-wordpress-plugin

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

wordpress - version-4.2.4

tinymce-advanced.3.4.9

when i open the setting it shows all the icons as shown below
[image]

i have added table icon into the field.

But when i see page bar it does not show it.

[image]

can any one help me on this please

console it says

**Deprecated TinyMCE API call: .onInit.add(..)**

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the changelog for TinyMCE Advanced, version 3.4.9 of that plugin states:

`Updated for WordPress 3.4 and TinyMCE 3.4.9.`

Per your original post you are not using WordPress 3.4 but rather WordPress 4.2.

WordPress 4.2.x uses TinyMCE 4 which would not be compatible with any code designed for TinyMCE 3.

I believe you need to run the correct version of TinyMCE Advanced for WP 4.2.4  Based on the changelog I suspect you need this version:

```
4.2.3.1
Fix error with removing the 'textpattern' plugin.
```

The change log for TinyMCE Advanced is accessible here:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/changelog/

Comment: Thanks for your reply . but it says  "TinyMCE Advanced requires WordPress version 4.5-beta or newer. It appears that you are running 4.2.4. This can make the editor unstable.
Please upgrade your WordPress installation or download an older version of the plugin."

Comment: i guess tinymce-advanced.3.4.9  shows all the editor tool  compared to other version.

Comment: The versions of TinyMCE Advanced are very tightly coupled to the WP version - did you grab the exact version I referenced above?

Comment: Yes I did the same